# looping through whole dataframe

Tags: r, loops

```
for (i in 1:49)

  i <- 1
    lat1 <- df1[1,6]
    lat2 <- df2[i,5]
    lon1 <- df1[1,7]
    lon2 <- df2[i,6]

    d= acos(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)+cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon1-lon2))
    if ((d < 8.05)){
          print("true")
          }else{
          print("false")
          }

i <- i+1}
```

I am having trouble with this loop, I am trying to have the code go through each i which represents the row in df 2 but I need the code to search for the given condition for every row in df1 (the column always stays the same).

I keep getting the error:

```
> In if ((d < 8.04672)) { ... : the condition has length > 1 and only
> the first element will be used
```

Comment: First try removing the `i <- 1` line.

Comment: Also, only the first line in the for loop is evaluated since there are no brackets.  Also, have  you changed the code at all?  The error has a different number than the one you have in the code above.

Comment: `d` is a vector with more than one element and that is why you have that error. But it is rather hard to guess why it is longer than 1 without exemplary `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: @user1362215 the only thing I changed was df names to make it clearer, that error is repeated 49 times

Comment: @RomanLuštrik thanks, it works after removing i <- 1 but I am getting all "true" when there should be some "false" I don't think it is looping through the elements the way I intended. I get [1] "true [1] "true 49 times

Comment: Doesn't `acos` output a value between `0` and `pi`..? So it makes sense that `d` is always smaller than `8.05`. Also, you may want to look up on how `for`-loops work, because you probably don't want to use `print` here.

Comment: @Laterow yes, when I convert from radians to degrees it works.... thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can write this much more efficiently, i.e. without loop:

```
lat1 <- df1[1,6]
lon1 <- df1[1,7]

lat2 <- df2[1:49,5]
lon2 <- df2[1:49,6]

d <- acos(sin(lat1)*sin(lat2)+cos(lat1)*cos(lat2)*cos(lon1-lon2))
d < 8.05
```

All functions that you use (`sin`,`cos` and `acos`) can take vectors as their input. Basic operators (in this case `*` and `-`) work element-by-element, so this also ensures that you manipulate each element separately. Thus, `d` will be a vector of all `acos` values.

Then you seem to want a logical vector (all values `TRUE` or `FALSE`). For this, just subject `d` to a logical operation (`>`). Since logical operators can also take vectors, all values will be evaluated on their truth value.